# Is it possible to retrieve the query mongodb compass uses when I visually modify a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm new to mongodb, and therefore it is still hard for me to create queries on my own. I found mongodb compass helpful to modify my documents, but would like to have queries in order to apply changes quicker to the production database.

Is there a way to modify a document visually using mongodb compass and then to get the query that mongodb compass uses behind the curtain?

If not, is there some different GUI application that could help me to create queries?

Comment: I don't see any such feature in Compass. To know about the update operations on MongoDB see this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: do you know a different GUI which offers a feature like this? (I am already using the mongodb docs but its just such a _slow_ process for me)

Comment: i use studio3t for this, robo3t is their free version but it's somewhat limited compared to the real product

Comment: @TomSlabbaert, do you know if robo3t supports this particular feature?

Comment: it does yes ...